# Can I apply for a StackOverflow 10M T-shirt?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Really like the community and would love to have one of the **10-million-questions** T-shirts.

However, I don't believe I am lucky enough to win the lucky draw.

Can I buy one of the T-shirts? I am willing to pay.